# How to scrape https website data using python and selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, https, phantomjs, ssl-certificate, python-3.4

I have been trying to scrape [www.zomato.com](http://www.zomato.com) for more than a week and now I have searched my problems over the net, but i could not found the proper solution for it. so i have posted my question over here.

Here is my code for the webscraper.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
import sys
import lxml
import unittest, time, re

class Sel(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='\phantomjs.exe')#phantom js
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(30)
        self.base_url = "https://www.zomato.com"
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.accept_next_alert = True
    def test_sel(self):
        driver = self.driver
        delay = 3
        driver.get(self.base_url + "hyderabad")
        driver.find_element_by_link_text("All").click()
        for i in range(1,100):
            self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
            time.sleep(4)
        html_source = driver.page_source
        data = html_source.encode('utf-8')


if __name__ == "__main__":
```

When I run in python 3.4 i.e., directory/py -3.4 selenium.py
I get this error
[selenium-python-phantomJS-SSL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8AcI.png).
Can anyone help me on this issue?
Best Regards.

Comment: paste the text from error messages, don't link to screenshots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the screenshot with errors you posted does *NOT* come from the code you posted.  Your code example shows you are invoking `webdriver.PhantomJS`, but the screenshot clearly shows you are getting the error when invoking `webdriver.Firefox`.

Also, the error message in the screenshot tells you exactly what the issue is and how to resolve it:  "geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH".

To use Firefox with selenium. you need to install geckodriver and make it available on your PATH.  geckodriver (like chromedriver) is an external component that does not ship with Firefox or Selenium... it must be installed separately.

You can download geckodriver here: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

Comment: Thanks will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the appropriate accept-encoding headers to your request.

'accept-encoding':'gzip, deflate, sdch, br'

Comment: Mate I am sorry but this isn't working same error like before